# Inversion in a sphere preserves circles (proof)

Tags: circles, alternative-proof, spheres, conformal-geometry, inversive-geometry

Inversion in the unit sphere, for a vector $x$, is defined by

$$\frac1x = \frac x{x^2} = \Big(\frac1{x\cdot x}\Big)x$$

How can we prove that a circle's inversion in the sphere is also a circle?

(I already have my own proof, but I didn't find this question elsewhere and thought it should exist. Feel free to improve the question or provide a different proof.)

Comment: How do you define $1/x,$ where $x$ is a vector? Is $x.x$ a dot product?

Comment: Yes. Different notations: $x^2=x\cdot x=\langle x,x\rangle=\langle x|x\rangle=|x|^2=\lVert x\rVert^2$ . Of course, the dot product is not invertible (because of orthogonal vectors) but the geometric product is invertible, so $x^{-1}$ makes sense. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry

Comment: Oh, this is a duplicate! I didn't search long enough. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2811216/how-to-prove-that-the-inversion-x-mapsto-fracx-lvert-lvert-x-rvert-rver